# Mercurial: Update File on Commit or Push

Tags: file, mercurial, auto-update

Currently, my team is using Mercurial.

In a previous work environment we used CVS and then Subversion and somehow it was set up that when we checked in our java classes that a field was updated.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private static final String ID = "$Id: MyObject.java 10000 2008-11-14 16:20:10Z userid $";

    // rest of class
}
```

The `$Id:` at the beginning and `$` at the end were used as regex delimiters.  When we did a commit, the ID string was updated such that 10000 would have been incremented to 10001, the date updated to the commit time and userid to the committer.  This came in handy when looking at deployed code and needing to know exactly what version of class was deployed because you could do a `strings` command on the class file and read that string.

We started this before there was Maven and better build/depency managment tools and for the most part this isn't needed anymore.

However, we've come across a situation where a project was merged/updated, the central Mercurial repo rebuilt from somebody's local one, and builds being done reverting the Maven version numbers... it's a bit of a mess.  We're not sure exactly what version of the classes have currently deployed.

Is there any way that I can set Mercurial up to do this type of update on a commit or a push to the central repository?  I haven't been able to find anything, but sometimes that's because the search terms are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mercurial Hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) for that. More specifically the **pre-commit** hook (you can find info on it on the [hgrc help](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/hgrc)).

For example, to write the current date on a file before every commit, set up in your hgrc (either on `~/.hgrc` or `project/.hg/hgrc`):

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = date > file.txt
```

The **pre-commit** setting must be set with a command to run before a commit is executed. For your case, you could write a shell script that *cat* and *sed* your java file to update the id with the new date and revision number.

The drawback of this solution is that you have to "deploy" that hgrc on every developer's machine to have the hook executed every time.

Comment: Thanks!  Reading the linked page about hooks talks about using the ``incoming`` hook for pushes to a central repository which is perfect for what we want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use at least two more easier (and more correct, BTW) ways

- Keywords  (any keywords, any data in keywords) in sources, controlled my Mercurial - see [Keyword Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) (instead of SVN-style revision number, use immutable changeset-hashes as ID)
- You can do nothing in SCM'ed code, but add needed data at the stage of build|deploy - read "Overview" part of extension wiki-page. Instead of `hg id` you, maybe, prefer to use [MercurialRev](https://bitbucket.org/JPlenert/mercurialrev) the same way, as SubWCRev for Subversion - repository store template-file, which have to be processed by lexer and only final file used in products

Comment: I looked at the Keyword Extension and noticed it's marked as a <i>feature of last resort</i> which doesn't inspire confidence in its use. Also, if I'm reading it correctly, it would only do the the keyword replacement once since after it's been expanded, there's no long a keyword to replace.  I want to read 10000 and update it to 10001 when committed/pushed , then to 10002 on the next commit/push etc.  Also, I'm afraid I really didn't understand your second bullet point.

Comment: @sdoca - keywords will be expanded (in Working Dir) after **each and every** change of related data. About p.2 - I sayd about situation, when you store in repository template file, but *use in code result of processing template* (hand-made) - read [Wiki page](https://bitbucket.org/JPlenert/mercurialrev/wiki/Home) of MercurialRev for sample of usage